# Can anyone explain full procedure of integrating App link for android in flutter?

Tags: flutter, applinks, android-app-links

Can anyone explain full procedure of integrating App link for android in flutter?

I want to learn, how to handle incoming link using App link in flutter app for android.
and how to use assetlinks.json file for our android app.

Comment: There is a cookbook in the official Flutter documentation that guides app links integration for Android: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links